# Why does Airbnb keep disabling my account?

Tags: airbnb

I try to post my house in United States but I am on a vacation in Africa. After posting my house Airbnb disables my account. Why?

Comment: This sounds like a support issue you should ask Airbnb directly.

Comment: This actually sounds a lot like an updated version of a common rental scam found on Craigslist. Not saying it is, but it does share some similar points. I'd guess AirBnB has rules preventing accounts with certain characteristics such as the account originating in certain locations while the offered house is in other certain locations to avoid such scams. Set up the account when you return to the US and you might not have that problem.

Answer (score 1):

This might be because of where you're located currently.  It seems like they wouldn't be able to tell where you're posting from, but they can.